# TesseractNotFoundError Using Anaconda/Jupyter

Tags: python, python-tesseract

I have installed Anaconda 2018.12 (Python 3.7 version). I am trying to test out the pytesseract module but I keep encountering:

*TesseractNotFoundError: C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe is not installed or it's not in your path*

I have done:

- pip install Pillow (already installed it says)
- pip install pytesseract (successful)
- Tried to set the tesseract_cmd to the location of tesseract (but I can't find it)

I have searched for the tesseract.exe file but cannot find it anywhere on the system so I'm struggling to understand how do I reference/import the module into a jupyter notebook if it's already been consumed into anaconda?

The code I'm trying to run is:

```
from PIL import Image 
import pytesseract
#pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe"

text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('C:\Temp\IMG_1519.jpg'))

print(text)
```

I'm hoping it's simple user error but any assistance would be gratefully received. Many thanks, Ben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting from the [PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/pytesseract/) page:

> Python-tesseract is a wrapper for Google’s Tesseract-OCR Engine.

and (under prequisites):

> Install Google Tesseract OCR (additional info how to install the engine on Linux, Mac OSX and Windows)

This means, that `pytesseract` is not a standalone module. It is a python wrapper for using the [Google’s Tesseract-OCR Engine](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract), which you need to install seperately

Comment: FlyingTeller: Thank you - all working now...I think the term I need to learn is RTFM :)  Appreciate the prompt response!